# Failed to load image Python extension : torchvision

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing, image-classification, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I have a python project base on computer vision, I want to create .exe file.

**I have successfully created .exe file but at the time of running .exe file it's not load image of live camera.
**

2023-12-05 13:57:42,302 - INFO - Connecting to camera at 182.78.217.70...
WARNING ⚠️ Unable to automatically guess model task, assuming 'task=detect'. Explicitly define task for your model, i.e. 'task=detect', 'se
gment', 'classify', or 'pose'.
torchvision\io\image.py:13: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: ''If you don't plan on using image functionality from `torchvision.io`, you can ignore this warning. Otherwise, there might be something wrong with your environment. Did you have `libjpeg` or `libpng` installed before building `torchvision` from source?
torch_jit_internal.py:857: UserWarning: Unable to retrieve source for @torch.jit._overload function: <function _DenseLayer.forward at 0x000002211EE61760>.

**How to solve this issue please give salution**

[image]

I want to make python file to .exe file.

but I am getting problem.

[image]